# R&OS php pdf € in a table

Tags: utf8-decode, ezpdf

I all, I'm using `R&OS` to generate PDF. Everything is fine until I start doing Invoices because I need to print currency. I used all my knowledge but nothing fixed my problem.

code is here:

```
$pdf->ezText(utf8_encode(getDescription()),12,array('justification' => 'center')); 
$pdf->ezSetDy(-10);
$pdf->ezText(utf8_encode(getCurrency()), 12, array('justification' => 'center')); 
$pdf->ezSetDy(-10);
```

`getDescription()` return strings that contains characters like "é,à,ç" and `getCurrency()` returns value like "€, $, £"
The PDF is fine with the description, I can see the specials characters, but the currency is always wrong.

For info, utf8_decode prints "?"
utf_encode prints "â,-" (something like that for the last character)

I'm looking for some help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I highly recommend you to use the latest version.
With this version you can build an unicode document (if necessary), but this requires unicode fonts (*.ufm)

For ansi output I have amended the font example with the euro glyph, so please have a look at:
[this example](http://pdf-php.sourceforge.net/pdf-php-code/examples/fonts.php) built using [this php code](http://pdf-php.sourceforge.net/pdf-php-code/examples/fonts.phps).

Comment: The links are broken.

Comment: it  is eventually easier to convert into utf8 using utf8_encode